# Can I autoselect a drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am taking text from a table via an autocomplete to pre-load information that was set to the table the last time the user was in it.  I can get the information without any problem.  Here is the jquery/javascript code that I am having the hard time with:

```
    $('#type').val(ui.item.type); 
    var t = $("#type").val();
    $('#types').text(t);
```

Here is the HTML code for the drop down menu:

```
    <label for="type"><strong>*</strong>Tournament Type</label>
        <select name="type" id="type">
        <option value="">Please select...</option><?
                                                    while ($type = mysql_fetch_array($types)) {
        $TID = $type['ID'];
        $name = htmlspecialchars($type['Type']);
        echo("<option value = '$name'>$name</option>\n");
                                                    }?>
        </select>
```

What I am trying to accomplish here is to make the displayed item on my drop down menu equal to what was previously selected while still maintaining the functionality of the drop down menu in case the information needs to be changed.  I have not been able to get this to work thus far.  Can I do this or is there another method I should be using to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
echo("<option selected value = '$name'>$name</option>\n")
```

on the one you want

or use jQuery after:

```
$("#type").val("someval")
```

Comment: The item I am looking to have displayed is contained in the jquery code snippet

Comment: sorry about that.  fat fingers!  Anyway,              $('#type').val(ui.item.type); contains the name.

Comment: I have tried your suggested jquery example too and it does not work

Comment: What does "Does not work" mean? Based on the minimal snippet you gave, it is hard to guess what might or might not work - can you create a jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/znjQn/  Never tried this jfiddle thing before.  Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: For testing purposes, the name 9 Pin No Tap (which is what my var t is) should show up where the phrase Please Select is

Comment: There is no such value present